# UITableView...the correct way

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, correctness

I'm trying to make a UITableView like the native calendar app:

[image]

but I'm trying to learn the best way to do this.  I'm able to get this for the most part with a switch statement in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, but I'm having troubles changing the textColor when a cell is selected.

For some reason cell.isSelected is always NO, and I have no way to reload the tableview after another cell is selected anyway.

Should I subclass UITableViewCell for something this simple and store an array of cells?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to subclass, as stated in the [app doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) the delegation function:

```
tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:
```

should do the trick

**EDIT:**

Below you find some code that should demonstrate the idea of using the delegate. Please note that this code is untested, as i am currently not in front of my xcode.

```
-(void)willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (prevIndexPath != nil) {
        UITableViewCell* prevCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: prevIndexPath];
        prevCell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor black]; // your initial color here
    }

    UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor green];

    prevIndexPath = indexPath;
}
```

Make sure to set the UITableViewDelegate protocol to your controlling class that manages your TableView and set the tableViews.delegate to that.

To make this code run, you also have to define a property or variable with the name prevIndexPath. This ones holds the previously selected cell that is needed to revert to the cell to its initial color.

Comment: so how do I change custom UILabels on the cells for all cells in the table?

Comment: Sorry if I'm unclear, but I'm trying to change the textColor of the custom labels (one says "Start" the other says "Thu, Feb 24, 5:10 PM") for cell 0 and cell 1.

Comment: updated the answer to change the font color of the cells textlabel.

Comment: the problem is that changes the text color of the current cell...but it won't change back to the original when another cell is selected...that also waits until the cell finishes selecting to change the color so that if the user presses, holds, the text color has not yet changed.  thanks for your help though.

Comment: update the answer. Note: instead of didSelectRowAtIndexPath: willSelectRowAtIndexPath is used.